# Selecting style in Google fonts

Tags: html, css, google-fonts

how to apply two different styles(bold in one section and regular in another section) of montserrat in css using google fonts? With the link provided in google fonts i can use only one

Comment: *With the link provided in google fonts i can use only one*, that is completely wrong, you can use multiple if you choose and link multiple font type

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you already did this but, the steps are, first, embedding the fonts. You can do this either by using a link tag on the HTML, like this:

```html
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;700&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

Or using an import on the CSS, like this:

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat:wght@400;700&display=swap');
```

After that, on your CSS, you need to use the correct font-family, like this:

```css
font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
```

And then specify the font-weight, like this:

```css
font-weight: 700;
```